# Android onCharacteristicChanged multiple packets at same timestamp

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an Android application that uses bluetooth LE to connect to our device.

One of the notifications that will come in from our device is whether it is on a charger or not.  This is a notification that fires once, and won't fire again until the status changes.

On iOS, this is all hunky-dory.

On Android, however, when connected to Android studio anyway, I will sometimes when running see a packet come into "onCharacteristicChanged" that is at time X, followed by the **exact same packet** at the **exact same time** to the **exact same characteristic**.

Sometimes when running, i'll only see one (expected).  Sometimes 2 copies of it, and sometimes 4 copies of it.

It's completely insane and I have no idea why it is happening.  I am not running my bluetooth stack as a service or anything.

Is this a "real" problem, or just a logging problem?  I ask because there are other packets we get in other characteristics that have sequence numbers (haven't enabled this yet), and I'm concerned that these packets will fail because we'll get duplicate sequence numbers!

Comment: I think you have enabled characteristic notification every time. make sure you have enabled it only first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.  I wasn't checking the the status in the **onConnectionStateChange** callback.  If I saw that the state was connected, i just blindly assigned the gatt and started the rest of my process to send commands to the device.

I think I also had an issue where i was always calling **connectGatt** instead of **connect** if the gatt already existed.

I have to say, while this is user error on my part, Android APIs are really idiotic in this regard.  You don't have to worry about which "connect" to call and monitor every state change callback, worrying about the thread you are on and whether certain objects are already allocated.